# Please explain below bash function

Tags: shell, function

I find this function online. It's does creating a directory and changing to directory.

But I want to know every part of it.

```
function mkdircd () { mkdir -p "$@" && eval cd "\"\$$#\""; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass in a list of names. It will create directories for each of them, then cd into the *last* one.

This does not need `eval`. I would write it like this:

```
mkdircd () { mkdir -p "$@" && cd "${!#}"; }
```

`${!#}` uses [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): `$#` is the number of parameters, so `${!#}` is the value of the last parameter

Comment: Still so much to learn. Thank you for link.

Comment: Of course if you've used brace expansion it still won't work as expected, will it?  E.g. `mkdircd dir{1..3}` will put you in the *first* of the three brace expanded dirs.

Comment: Yes, no problem: brace expansion occurs *before* the function is called, so you are passing 3 distinct arguments in that example.

Comment: Ahh, good point.  Whereas `cd dir{1..3}` will put you in `dir1`.

Comment: This doesn't need `eval` in bash, but using `eval` makes it work in other shells.

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir -p "$@"` create all the directories which name are passed as arguments (`$@`).

The `-p` option allow to create recursively the directories if they are in directories which don't exist.

`eval cd "\"\$$#\""` just go to the last directory: `$#` give you the number of argument passed, thus `\$$#` will give you the last argument (i.e: the last directory name you passed as an argument). For example, if there are three arguments, `$#` is `3`, so `eval` runs the command `cd "$3"`.

The command should actually have been `eval cd "\"\${$#}\""`. The braces are necessary in many shells when there are 10 arguments are more, because many shells treat something like `"$10"` as the value of parameter 1 followed by the character `0` and not as the value of parameter 10.